# I need to choose an SSD to suit my motherboard, either M.2 or SATA III

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata, m.2

I admit upfront my ignorance of modern PC architecture, I stopped building a few years ago, but I want to add an SSD to my own system, either M.2 card (SAMSUNG 970 EVO 'MZ-V7E1T0BW' NVMe 1TB, or a SATA III drive (Samsung 860EVO 1TB, although Seagate’s ST1000DM010 looks an awful lot cheaper!).

The current basics are:

CPU: QuadCore Intel Core i7-4790K, 4300 MHz

Motherboard: Asus Z97-Pro Gamer(2 PCI, 2 PCI-E x1, 3 PCI-E x16, 1 M.2, 4 DDR3 DIMM)  - manual is [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97PRO_GAMER/HelpDesk_Manual/).

DIMM: 2 x DIMM1- Crucial CT102464BD160B.M16 - 8 GB DDR3-1600 DDR3 SDRAM

Graphics: nVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 - (4 GB) - dual slot card

HD: Disk Drive  SanDisk SDSSDXPS480G - (480 GB, SATA-III)

A Wireless Network Adapter takes up PCIEX_1 which is next to the M2 slot. The M.2 slot has screw fitting for maximum 80mm cards.

I only see 2 x SATA 6Gb/s connectors on the ASUS mobo though, one serves my current SSD (boot drive, which I want to keep in place), and one my CD/DVD writer (very rarely used).

So, to keep it simple, am I limited to using the M.2 slot? I don’t want an HDD. I would like SATA III, though, in case my next mobo doesn’t have an M.2 slot (likelihood or that?).

Or would a USB3 SSD be around as fast as both options? I have an unused USB3 terminal on my motherboard and could drop a USB SSD in the case.

I’m happy with my current rig for gaming - Metro Exodus, Cyberpunk 2027, etc. run very smoothly. I’m looking for the same or faster transfer speeds.

Thanks in advance, guys, if you might give me any pointers.

John

Comment: It’s more likely your motherboard won’t have a SATA port than not having at least one M.2 NVMe slot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Specs](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97PRO_GAMER/specifications/) of your motherboard say:

> **Storage**
>
> - 1 x SATA Express port, compatible with 2 x SATA 6.0 Gb/s ports
> - 1 x M.2 Socket 3, , with M Key, type 2260/2280 storage devices support (both SATA & PCIE mode)*1
> - 4 x SATA 6Gb/s port(s), gray

So we learn that:

1. There are 4 regular SATA ports on the motherboard (visible on [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOjNU.jpg)).
2. There's a SATA Express port (also visible on the photo) that could be adapted into SATA or PCIe
3. The M.2 M-key slot supports both SATA and NVMe drives

The manual also adds an important detail:

> M.2 Socket 3 shares bandwidth with PCIEx1_1 and PCIEx1_2 (in PCIE mode) and SATA6G_4 (in SATA mode), and supports M Key and type 2260/2280 storage devices.

So when the M.2 slot is populated with an NVMe drive, PCIe x1 slots will be disabled - these lanes are then connected to the M.2 slot. When it's operating in SATA mode, one of the horizontally stacked SATA ports is disabled (probably the middle one).

So your options are:

1. Use a regular 2.5" SATA drive. You still have two unpopulated SATA ports. Even if one of them would get disabled by an additional M.2 SATA drive in the future there's still one extra.
2. Use a M.2 SATA drive. This will disable one of the SATA ports. If something is connected to it, you'll have to use another SATA port. All of them are connected directly to the chipset, so all ports are equally good.
3. Use a M.2 NVMe drive. These are generally faster than M.2 SATA (not always though - look at the specs) because they use the faster PCIe interface. This will, however, disable PCIe x1 slots - but you can move the WiFi card to a free x16 slot. That's the great thing about PCIe: it's very flexible.

Regarding future-proofing the new hardware, I'll just quote @Ramhound's comment:

> It’s more likely your motherboard won’t have a SATA port than not having at least one M.2 NVMe slot

But just in case you somehow get a motherboard without an M.2 slot:

- Regular PCIe slots can be adapted to a M.2 PCIe slot that will support NVMe drives
- Regular SATA ports can be connected to M.2 SATA adapters

**In summary:**

- If you don't mind paying extra, get a fast M.2 NVMe drive and move the WiFi card to a x16 slot.
- Otherwise a M.2 SATA drive should be a good choice.

Comment: NVMe 4.0 is the newest specification, SATA has received an updated specification in years.  It’s more likely that only M.2 drives will be released in the coming decade.  SATA is used by mechanical drives and optical drives.  Most OEM hardware doesn’t come with an optical drive.  Most cases released in the last 2 years doesn’t have a 5.25” slot (I.e for an optical drive).  Takes no additional engineering effort to provide SATA ports and M.2 slots.  Intel and AMD will actually drive how long SATA is around.

Comment: gronostaj, Thank for the so speedy and detailed reply, it's absolutely what I needed, and easy to follow.

I now understand that the SanDisk SSD and the DVD writer are both in the SATA Express slot. - https://imgur.com/vum7Rb5

The SATA slots are hidden behind the Graphic card, but I think are accessible - https://imgur.com/VSqPnr9

The M.2 slot isn't obscured by the Wifi card in PCIEX1_1, but I follow you that I will need to move it to PCIEX1_2 because the other will be disabled.
- https://imgur.com/j1NsDNf

Thanks so much for this, I couldn't have paid for better advice.  :)

Comment: Thank Ramhound, I can see that I don't need to worry about an M.2 card not being transferrable to a new mobo.

Comment: @Brighty Disregard my previous comment, you're right! The light gray port with three connectors is a single SATA Express.

Comment: You really should update your question with those screenshots instead of putting them in a temporary commentary that will likely eventually be deleted

Comment: Except I did the same as gronostaj did before me. And FYI I haven't deleted any images from imgur for the past 8 years I've used it.
But I have no objection to updating ('editing', I guess?) my comment. Are you saying that I can upload images to this board (or whatever it is)? Some forums don't like it because of data restrictions.

Comment: @Brighty Imgur images on free accounts expire when they aren't viewed. Meanwhile this website uses an unlimited account that's not prone to link rot.

Comment: @gronostaj - so my SDD and dvd writer are connected to a single SATA Express ports individually, and so I can't connect a second SATA III drive and achieve the same transfer rates? Or would the SATA6G ports suffice? 

That's if I didn't go the M.2 route (which I guess I might though, after investigating).

Comment: @gronostaj - ah thanks. you used an imgur link in your comment?  :)

I have images 5 years old on a free imgur account that have never even been viewed once, but they are still there!

Comment: Without a M.2 SATA drive all 6 of your SATA ports are usable. With a M.2 SATA drive one of the ports (specifically number 4) gets disabled. Connecting a PCIe device to the SATA Express port (the small connector) will also disable two SATA Express SATA ports I think. Anyway, SATA ports 1, 2 and 3 are always available. That's the two rightmost ports and one in the middle stack.

Comment: Regarding the imgur thing, as I said this website is using an unlimited imgur account. Note the `.stack` part in my imgur links. You can upload images to that account in the post editor.

Comment: @gronostaj - thank you. I don't want to try your patience too far, so just one more question please. I assume there is really no performance difference in a SATA III drive connected to a SATA Express port instead of to a regular SATA port, correct?

And re imgur, all noted and thanks for the explanation. I'll edit my post some time tomorrow to include permalinks to the images.

Comment: That's correct, all 6 of these SATA ports are identical. They're all 6Gb ports connected directly to the chipset without any extra bridges. It doesn't matter which one you use, just make sure it doesn't get reserved for a different port (as explained in the previous comment).

Comment: Thanks again for your kindness and patience. 

Comment: You're welcome! You can mark my answer as accepted (checkmark to the left). This will mark the question as solved and give me a few reputation points.